# How to pass multi-dimensional array to header file in C++

Tags: c++, c++11, multidimensional-array, header-files

I am trying to work with multi-dimensional arrays.
My goal is to have a separate file for my matrix functions, however I am having trouble with setting the value of `V`.

Error : `‘V’ was not declared in this scope`
Since this error statement is very broad, I could not find a satisfactory answer on my searches.

This is what I want to implement.

main.cpp

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h> 
using namespace std;
#include "prims.h"

int main()  
{   int V = 5;
    int graph[V][V] = { {... },  
                        {... },  
                        {... },   
                        {... },   
                        {... } };    
    func1(graph);
    func2(graph); 
    return 0;  
}
```

prims.h

```
#ifndef PRIMS_H
#define PRIMS_H
#include <bits/stdc++.h> 
using namespace std;

int func1(int graph[V][V]);
int func2(int graph[V][V]);

#endif
```

prims.cpp

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h> 
using namespace std;
#include "prims.h"

int func1(int graph[V][V])  
{  
  // function
} 

int func2(int graph[V][V])  
{  
  // function
}
```

Please comment below if more clarification is required.
Thank you.

Comment: `V` is not defined anywhere, and the compiler is telling you about it.

Comment: I understand that, how do I implement what I want ?

Comment: Use a namespace

Comment: as the above comments already suggest 'V' needs to be defined somewhere OR if its defined somewhere then that header is not included. use a class and make those functions as members of the class OR if that is too much work then use a namespace. [more about namespace here](https://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/4-3b-namespaces/)

Comment: Are you serious?  You are referencing an identifier that doesn't exist.  What value do you want?  42?  Okay, so define it as a constant, maybe in `prims.h` _i.e._ `const int V = 42;`

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to put  `V`  in my question. I'll make the edit.

Comment: See also: [Why should I not #include <bits/stdc++.h>?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31816095/673852)

Comment: Your current code has `main` changing the types of the parameters that `func1` takes. That can't work. How would code in `func1` even know the value of `V` since it's not passed in?

Comment: `std::vector<std::vector<int>>` might be more appropriate, (or create dedicated `class Matrix` or use on from existing lib).

Answer (score 2):

Since you want to set the value from main, one alternative is to declare `V` as global variable in `main` and as `extern const int` in prims.h, so that it is visible in prmis.cpp as well.

**prims.h**

```
extern const int V;
```

**main.cpp**

```
const int V = 5; //declared as global in main
int main()  
{  
   /* */
}
```